# How do I convert C# .net code to angular 9

Tags: angular, jwt, angular9

Can anyone help me out please. I've been looking on a way to convert this code to angular. been struggling lately because I'm new to angular. Please help me out. I have no idea on how to do this.

```
            string key = "secretkey";

            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

            var request = new RequestSampleModel
            {
                sampledata1 = "testdata1",
                sampledata2 = "testdata2"
            };

            Claim[] claimsdata = new Claim[] {
                    new Claim("sampledata1", "testdata1"),
                    new Claim("sampledata2", "testdata2")
                };

            var generatedtoken = new JwtSecurityToken(
             claims: claimsdata,
             signingCredentials: credentials
            );
```

Comment: Hello, could you show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout honestly i've tried many things but nothing seems to work. I've already deleted my converted code. I've loosing hope

Comment: When you say convert to angular you want to translate it to typescript? Or should it be converted to javascript?

Comment: typescript sir @Tommi